# Использование computeIfAbsent из Map

Tags: java

Как пользоваться методом `computeIfAbsent`? Как он работает, и в каком случае выполняется?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Методу [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) передаётся два параметра: ключ `key` и функция расчета значения по этому ключу `mappingFunction`.

Логика работы метода:

- Проверяем наличие такого ключа в map. Если ключ есть и значение по ключу не равно `null`, то ничего не делаем
- Иначе (нет ключа или значение по ключу равно `null`) считаем значение, применяя `mappingFunction` к `key`
- Если итоговое значение не равно `null`, то записываем пару ключ-значение в map

В виде кода эта логика в документации описывается так:

```
if (map.get(key) == null) {
    V newValue = mappingFunction.apply(key);
    if (newValue != null)
        map.put(key, newValue);
}
```

---

В некоторых ситуациях достаточно будет метода [putIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-), особенно если вычисляемое значение вообще не зависит от ключа.
Например, если в `Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map` нужно просто положить новый список по ключу:

```
map.putIfAbsent(key, new ArrayList<>());
```

Вот если при этом хочется сразу и значение положить в этот список, то тут удобнее будет `computeIfAbsent`:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(100);
```

вместо

```
map.putIfAbsent(key, new ArrayList<>());
map.get(key).add(100);
```

---

[Хорошим примером](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19283210/3432401) использования метода `computeIfAbsent` с запоминанием результата является вычисление [чисел Фибоначчи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8):

```
private static Map<Integer, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
static
{
    map.put(0, 0L);
    map.put(1, 1L);
}

public static long fibonacci(int x)
{
    return map.computeIfAbsent(x, n -> fibonacci(n - 2) + fibonacci(n - 1));
}
```

И вызов:

```
System.out.println(fibonacci(10));
```

> 55

Comment: А если ключ существует а value == null?

Comment: @alexsafsafsd так ведь это относится к "В противном случае"